# Keras LSTM model - expected to have 3 dimensions, but got array with 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Currently working on a financial time series LSTM model with Keras, and ran into this problem.

It seems that my code is generating is generating a node with 2 dimensions where 3 is expected, here is the code,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Dense, GRU, Embedding, LSTM, Flatten
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, 
ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard, ReduceLROnPlateau


batch_size = 500
feature_no = 13
period_no = 8640
def gen(batch_size, periods):
j = 0

features = ['ask_close',
            'ask_open',
            'ask_high',
            'ask_low',
            'bid_close',
            'bid_open',
            'bid_high',
            'bid_low',
            'open',
            'high',
            'low',
            'close',
            'price']
with pd.HDFStore('datasets/eurusd.h5') as store:
    df = store['train_buy']

x_shape = (batch_size, periods, len(features))
x_batch = np.zeros(shape = x_shape, dtype=np.float16)

y_shape = (batch_size, periods)
y_batch = np.zeros(shape = y_shape, dtype=np.float16)

while True:
    i = 0
    while len(x_batch) < batch_size:
        if df.iloc[j+periods]['direction'].values == 1:
            x_batch[i] = df.iloc[j:j+periods][features].values.tolist()
            y_batch[i] = df.iloc[j+periods]['target_buy'][0].round(4)
            i+=1
        j+=1
        if j == 56241737 - periods:
            j = 0
    yield x_batch, y_batch

generator = gen(batch_size, period_no)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 1, return_sequences=True, input_shape = (None, feature_no,)))


optimizer = RMSprop(lr=1e-3)
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = optimizer)
model.fit_generator(generator=generator, epochs = 10, steps_per_epoch = 112483)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
model.fit_generator(generator=generator, epochs = 10, steps_per_epoch = 112483)
File "C:\Users\Seok\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\models.py", line 1198, in fit_generator
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
File "C:\Users\Seok\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\engine\training.py", line 2345, in fit_generator
x, y, sample_weight=sample_weight, class_weight=class_weight)
File "C:\Users\Seok\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\engine\training.py", line 1981, in train_on_batch
check_batch_axis=True)
File "C:\Users\Seok\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\engine\training.py", line 1514, in _standardize_user_data
exception_prefix='target')
File "C:\Users\Seok\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\engine\training.py", line 139, in _standardize_input_data
'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lstm_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (500, 8640)
```

I have seen similar issues on gibhub, and they seem to have resolved this problem, however the solution there did not seem to work on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSTM (and GRU) layers require 3 dimensional inputs: a batch size, a number of time steps, and a number of features.
<strike>In `input_shape` terms, they are specified as `(batch size, time steps, no. of features)`.
So just eyeballing your code, you should change</strike>

`model.add(LSTM(units = 1, return_sequences=True, input_shape = (None, feature_no,)))`

to

`model.add(LSTM(units = 1, return_sequences=True, input_shape = (batch_size, periods, len(features)))`

EDIT: Mistake on my part, input_shape is not specified as a 3-dimensional array, but expects a 3-d array as input to the model.

I believe the error here is actually caused by the output shape. With `return_sequences = True`, the output of an LSTM has the shape `(batch_size, timesteps, units)`, and so the generator should be producing `y_batch` arrays of shape `(batch_size, periods, 1)`

Comment: No, this is wrong - Keras LSTM does need data of 3 dimensions - and will accept the data generated by the generator above which produces data with 3 dimensions - 

However, when calling the LSTM layer, Keras does not expect batch size to be included in the input_shape parameter, and raise an error when input_shape is called with 3 dimensions - try for yourself.

Comment: Read through the Keras documentation on RNNs, specifically the output shape. You have `return_sequences` set to true. The output of the LSTM is then a 3-dimensional tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, units). Your generator is yielding output arrays (y_batch) of shape `(batch_size, periods)`. Since you have 1 LSTM unit, this should be `(batch_size, periods, 1)`
Keras documentation on LSTMs/RNNs is here https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/

Comment: And sorry, you're right, `input_shape` shouldn't be specified as a 3-dimensional shape, but inputs do need to be 3d. I'll edit the answer above now.

Comment: Thanks for that,
I have tried to run the code with returen_sequences = False, then it raises an error like this - 
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lstm_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (8640,)

Comment: Ah, I see the problem

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - 1, as platinum95 said, return_sequences option on LSTM layer should only be used when passing the nodes to another LSTM layer,

Also, the shape of y_batch in generator was called wrong. It should have been shape (batch_size)

Answer (score 0):

It is about the nature of models that sequential models like RNNs LSTMs and GRUs require 3D not like non-sequential models LR RF and SVM.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).